# Append to end of associative array in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have an array which is defined as $array[colname]. For each value in $array[colname], I would like to append a piece of text to the end. The value already inside is string and I will append a string as well.

Comment: You can't append in an orderly manner to an associative array..

Comment: you can use array_walk()

Comment: Wait, do you only want to append to a single column or do you want to append to every item? (Is your array a matrix/table?) Where does your data come from? If it comes from a database, why not append the string directly in your query/when transforming the resultset into your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? You can easily iterate throug arrays

Here are the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Tip: Next time you should search on google and php.net because most default stuff are documented and in your question you used the right keywords that you needed to find it yourself

```
<?php
//Could write this shorter
$array = array(); 
$array['column1'] = 'value1';
$array['column2'] = 'value2';

//This is the short way
//http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
$array = array('column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2');

//Iterate throug every value in $array (That is every $array[colname])
//The & charachter before the $value means  pass-by-reference you should do some research to understand this ;)

//foreach($array['colname'] as &$value) {  for a single column with multiple values in it
foreach($array as &$value) {

    // .=  is the same as   $value = $value . 'append'
    // This way we append the text
    $value .= 'append'; 
}
//Outputs all values in $array
print_r($array());
?>
```

Comment: Hey. THanks for the answer and tip. I did. I didn't understand the documentation. I am also not understanding your answer. How does this ensure that the text is appended only to $array[colname]?

Comment: How do you mean only? you want to append some text to every value in $array right?

Comment: I added some comments, just play with it =) you will understand it

Comment: And you can iterate a column like this: 
foreach($array['colname'] as &$value)

Comment: Your last comment did it for me. Thanks!

I don't understand all the hostility around the question. I obviously searched for a solution first. I didn't understand it that's why I made the effort of typing it out as a question. 

I'm sorry I can't upvote your answer. My reputation was brought below 15 points after this question.

Comment: No problem, and yes they downvote pretty quick here without telling you why. Also some simple questions are mostly voted down because the answer could be easily found on the internet but some people try to learn or just started learning without an education but with intrests. I think they just need a push in the right direction wich works a lot better then just voting it all down

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two possibilities

1. Edit the array in place:

   ```
   foreach($a as &$v) {
     $v .= 'APPENDED';
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   foreach($a as $k => $v) {
     $a[$k] = $v . 'APPENDED';
   }
   ```
2. Create a new array by [mapping](http://php.net/array_map) the old values to their new values:

   ```
   $appended_array = array_map(function($v) { return $v . 'APPENDED'; }, $a);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_walk like below:

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $string)
{
    $item1 = "$item1 : $string";
}

array_walk($fruits, 'test_alter', 'fruit');
echo "... and after:\n";

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

Output will be like this:

```
... and after:
d. lemon:fruit
a. orange:fruit
b. banana:fruit
c. apple:fruit
```

for more info:http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: This is prepending not appending ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the tested solution provided array matches to your stucture

```
<?php

$array = array();

$array['c1'] = array(1=>'data1', 2=>'data2', 3=>'data3', 4=>'data4');
$array['c2'] = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

echo '<pre> Original Array : <br/>';

print_r($array);

foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{

    foreach($value as $sub_key=>$sub_value)  
    {
        $textToAppend = '_AppendedMe';
        echo '<br/> brfore : '.$value[$sub_key];
        $sub_value .= $textToAppend;


        $array[$key][$sub_key]=$sub_value;

        echo '<br/> after : '.$value[$sub_key];
    }

}
echo '<br/> Array after : ';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```